# What are the preferred protocols to integrate external data sources & sinks with a BC network?

Tags: dapp-development

I'd like to trigger events and send data to external non-ethereum network applications. What is the preferred communication protocol and mechanism to use so as not to impact BC processing?

My understanding is that external events and data can be input to the BC using normal transactions but are there alternative input mechanisms?

Comment: BC means blockchain?  Please also clarify the question.  A suggestion is to make it more specific.  What do you want to integrate?  Transactions are how data is put on a blockchain: what alternative mechanisms are you envisioning?

Comment: Yes. BC == blockchain. Here's my scenario. A blockchain app is deployed and runs the same contract state machine in all nodes. At one of the state transitions, a JSON-encoded message needs to be sent to an external application endpoint somewhere on the internet to trigger an action. The contract specifies the endpoint. All nodes send the same message to the same endpoint and all messages except the first are filtered out. Each message sent should not interfere with the blockchain's execution and should probably be executed asynchronously in a separate thread.

Comment: This would be easy in a normal everyday Java/Python app using JASON-RPC, sockets, etc. but the blockchain runs in a special virtual machine. Ideally, I'd like to include AMQP and MQTT libs and send to a service bus but 'm not familiar enough with the Homestead programming platform and it's constraints. Can I add these libs to my app and execute on the Ethereum platform? Does this help? I can elaborate more if needed.  Thx Much!